# unique minimum spanning tree sufficient and necessary conditions

Tags: graph, proof, minimum-spanning-tree

Given a graph G,which are the sufficient and necessary conditions , so that this graph has a unique minimum spanning tree?In addition , how can I proove these conditions?

So far , I  had found that those conditions are :

1)For every partition of V(G) into two subsets, the minimum weight edge with one endpoint in each subset is unique.

2)The maximum-weight edge in any cycle of G is unique.

But I am not sure if this is correct.Even in case this is correct,I cannot prove its correctness.

Comment: The [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to post this question.

Comment: Actually , it has already been asked at Computer Science Stak Exchange but no answer has been given unfortunately.

Comment: Try the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com) then.

Comment: Also, based on the comments for [this question on the CS-SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/34015/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-unique-minimum-spanning-tree), it looks like these conditions are *not* sufficient and necessary, and that the question should be "prove or disprove" rather than "prove."

Comment: @hatchet, I know you're just trying to help this user, but for the future, if you're going to suggest another site, could you remind the user to avoid cross-posting?  You can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere.  That will help ensure a better experience for them.  Also, so you know, CS.SE has certain question quality expectations: we expect people to show us what progress they've made so far and where they got stuck, and ask a specific question about the exercise, when asking exercise-style questions.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755.

Comment: It appears you have copied text word-for-word directly from [lecture notes by Jeff Erickson](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/20-mst.pdf) (Exercise 3(b), p.8), without crediting your source.  [Plagiarism](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715).  Please make sure to properly credit your sources.

Comment: In fact , I don't even know Jeff Erickson. I copied the question from my university homework.

Comment: @user3697730, OK, you copied it from your university homework.  The general point remains: you should still credit your source -- whereever you copied it from, you should acknowledge the source of the material in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is a necessary and sufficient condition for unique MST. In the book [A First Course In Graph Theory](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486483681.html), it is given as an exercise:

> Exercise 4.30
>
> Let G be a connected weighted graph and T a minimal spanning tree of G. Show that T is a unique minimal spanning tree of G if and only if the weight of each edge e of G that is not in T exceeds the weight of every other edge on the cycle in T+e.

I write my proof [here](https://rivers-shall.github.io/2018/11/19/Necessary-And-Sufficient-Condition-for-Unique-MST/).

Answer (score 3):

This is false because at least the first condition is not necessary.  The proof is by counterexample ([source](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/34015/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-unique-minimum-spanning-tree)).

> Take G to be any tree where all edge weights are 1. Then G has a
>   unique MST (itself), but any partition with more than one edge
>   crossing it has several minimum weight edges.

---

EDIT:

In response to your modified question...

There is a well-known sufficient (but not necessary) condition for the uniqueness of a MST:

> If the weight of each edge in a connected graph is distinct, then the graph contains exactly one (unique) minimum spanning tree.

The proof is as follows ([source](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/43mst/)):

> For the sake of contradiction, suppose there are two different MSTs of
>   G, say T1 and T2. Let e = v-w be the min weight edge of G that is in
>   one of T1 or T2, but not both. Let's suppose e is in T1. Adding e to
>   T2 creates a cycle C. There is at least one edge, say f, in C that is
>   not in T1 (otherwise T1 would be cyclic). By our choice of e, w(e) ≤
>   w(f). Since all of the edge weights are distinct, w(e) < w(f). Now,
>   replacing f with e in T2 yields a new spanning tree with weight less
>   than that of T2 (contradicting the minimality of T2).

However, regarding "sufficient *and* necessary" conditions for the uniqueness of a MST, I do not believe any are known to exist.