# It is possible for a graph to have multiple minimum spanning trees

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

Let G=(V, E) be an undirected graph, all whose edges have a unique weight. Is it true
that G has a single unique MST? Or can G also have multiple MSTs?

Comment: The answer would, probably be `no`; multiple STs are possible (depends on the graph), but, if each edge has a `unique weight`, only one MST will be possible.

Comment: @anurag can you please elaborate it further? More reasons why it is not possible?

Comment: @anurag: I don't think that weight uniqueness is sufficient.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I cannot currently think of a case where more than one MST can be generated when edges have unique weights! `Prim` and `Kruskal` algorithms can generate different MSTs only when the uniqueness constraint is absent!

Comment: The MST is unique, and the question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192157/unique-minimum-spanning-tree-sufficient-and-necessary-conditions

Comment: Is A-B different from B-A?

Comment: @Surt if you are asking whether edge `A-B` is different from edge `B-A` then the answer is **Yes** for directed graphs and **No** for undirected graphs!

Comment: @alphaT123 I have added a "proof by contradiction" to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the definition of MST (source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)) -

> A minimum spanning tree (MST) or minimum weight spanning tree is a subset of the edges of a connected, edge-weighted undirected graph that connects all the vertices together, without any cycles and with the minimum possible total edge weight.

The goal is to cover **all** vertices while having the **lowest** edge weight sum. Also, a spanning tree (ST) is a *tree*, so no cycles -

[image]

In the image above, the orange trees are STs, but, only the top one can be an MST (edge weight sum is 7).

---

**EDIT**

*Proof by contradiction*:

Let [image: G(V,E)] be an undirected graph with unique edge weights. Let [image: T_1] and [image: T_2] be two **distinct** Minimum Spanning Trees for the graph.

Let [image: e_1] be the edge with lowest weight present in [image: T_1], but, not in  [image: T_2]. Similarly, let [image: e_2] be the edge in [image: T_2], but, not in [image: T_1].

Now, since edge weights are unique, without loss of generality, let [image: w(e_1)<w(e_2)].

Also, if we add [image: e_1] in [image: T_2], a cycle will form with [image: e_2]. To remove the cycle, let us remove the edge [image: e_2] from [image: T_2]. Thus, we have a Spanning Tree [image: T = T_2 U e_1 / e_2].

This ST, [image: T], now has total weight less than [image: T_2]; but, this is a contradiction, since, [image: T_2] was already an MST.

Thus, our assumption that, [image: G(V,E)] had two MSTs to begin with was wrong. This concludes the proof.

Comment: You've only showed it for one example, but the question was about *all* undirected weighted graphs with unique weights.

Comment: @MoB. To prove any concept wrong, we need just one counter example. I understand, that my answer doesn't do that, but, it was meant to be an example. The standard algorithms for MST are Prim and Kruskal; and they do not have the unique edge weight constraint.